# vite build html parser throws error on html in javascript string

Tags: vite, html-framework-7

I am using framework7 v7 and capacitor which uses vite as bundler. I can run the page in dev mode but when i want to compile it for android i get a parse error. I just can't figure out why. i have tried using " instead of ' in the js string and also tried separate lines instead of a concated string. the only change was that the error is at a different position '<span

i have just updated from the old framework7 that uses webpack v4.x and it compiled there without trouble.

it has to be something with html in javascript variables. maybe a setting that disables the html validation is js?

error:

```
[vite:build-html] Unable to parse HTML; 15
 at {"file":"/home/aow/workspace/dentaLink/src/pages/app/noCon.f7.html","line":160,"column":36}
158|                tmp += '<br/><span>';
159|              } else {
160|                tmp += '<span class="' + (f.pos == 'anam' ? 'answer' : '') + '">';
   |                                     ^
161|              } //add text field
162|
```

here is the html file:

```
    <template>
  <div class="page" data-name="home" id="noCon">
    <div class="page-content app-content">
  ${registration && $h`
      <div class="tabs tabs-sub">
        <div class="sub-nav editBlock">
          <a href="#tab-reg-allAgb" class="tab-link tab-link-active">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('allAgb')}</a>
          <a href="#tab-reg-user" class="tab-link">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('user')}</a>
          <a href="#tab-reg-anam" class="tab-link">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('anamnese')}</a>
          <a href="#tab-reg-clientAgb" class="tab-link">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('clAgb')}</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab tab-active list" id="tab-reg-allAgb">
          <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab list" id="tab-reg-user">
        <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-firstname">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('firstname')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" tabindex="1" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('firstname')}" required ${isProfile && $h`disabled`}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-surname">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('surname')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" tabindex="2" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('surname')}" required ${isProfile && $h`disabled`}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-street">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('street')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="street" id="street" tabindex="3" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('street')}" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-zip">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('zip')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" tabindex="4" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('zip')}" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-city">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('city')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" tabindex="5" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('city')}" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-country">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('country')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country" tabindex="6" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('country')}" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-email">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('email')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="9" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('email')}" ${!app.f7.mod.user.isServicedesk() && $h`required`}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-phone">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('phone')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="10" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('telNr')}"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label" id="lbl-gender">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('gender')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap input-dropdown-wrap">
                <select name="gender" id="gender" tabindex="11" class="field" required ${isProfile && $h`disabled`}>
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="m">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('male')}</option>
                  <option value="f">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('female')}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="lastStatic">
          <div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-floating-label">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('birthday')}</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="birthday" id="birthday" tabindex="12" class="field" placeholder="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('birthday')}" required ${isProfile && $h`disabled`}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab list" id="tab-reg-anam">
          <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab list" id="tab-reg-clientAgb">
          <ul></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-anamnese">
          <button @click="${() => back()}" accesskey="r" tabindex="55" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('back')}</button>
          <button @click="${() => next()}" accesskey="s" tabindex="54" class="btn-submit button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('next')}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `}

    ${!registration && $h`
      <div class="error"></div>
      ${!app.f7.store.state.user || app.f7.store.state.user.noCon ? $h`
        <div class="scan">
          <button @click="${() => scanQr()}" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('qrScan')}</button>
        </div>
      ` : ''}

      ${app.f7.mod.user.isServicedesk() ? $h
        `<div class="scan flex-direction-column">
          ${msg ? $h`
            <p class="info" innerHTML="${msg}"></p>
          ` : ''}
        </div>
        <div class="scan">
          ${cookie && app.f7.mod.user.isServicedesk() &&
            $h `<span><b>${doc && doc.firstname + ' ' + doc.surname}...</b></span>
              <button @click="${() => register(app.f7.store.state.clientId, app.f7.store.state.settings.title)}" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng(app.f7.mod.user.isServicedesk() ? 'edit' : 'register')}</button>`
          }
          <br/><br/><button @click="${() => reset()}" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('new')}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="scan flex-direction-row margin-top">
          <span>${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('lang')}:</span>
          <span class="link" @click="${() => changeLang('de')}">de</span>
          <span class="link" @click="${() => changeLang('en')}">en</span>
        </div>`

      : $h`
        ${app.f7.store.state.user && !app.f7.store.state.user.noCon ? $h`
          <div class="scan">
            <button @click="${() => app.f7.store.dispatch('replicate')}" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('reload')}</button><br/>
            <button @click="${() => app.f7.store.dispatch('logout')}" class="button button-raised button-fill">${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('logout')}</button>
          </div>
        ` : ''}
        <div class="scan flex-direction-column">
        ${msg ? $h`
          <p class="info" innerHTML="${msg}"></p>
        ` : ''}
        </div>

        <h2>${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('clients')}</h2>
        ${list ? $h`
          ${list.map((item) => $h`
            <div class="card client">
              <div class="card-header">${item.doc.title}</div>
              <div class="card-content" id="c${item.doc.clientId}">
                <i class="f7-icons float-left">photo</i>
                <span>${item.doc.city}, ${item.doc.offering}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="${app.f7.mod.helper.getMaps()}${item.doc.street},${item.doc.zip} ${item.doc.city}" target="_blank" id="lnkMap" class="external f7-icons">map_pin_ellipse</a>
                <i @click="${() => register(item.doc.clientId, item.doc.title)}" class="f7-icons link right" title="${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('register')}">person_crop_circle_badge_plus</i>
              </div>
            </div>
          `)}
        ` : ''}
        ${!list ? $h`
            <p>${app.f7.mod.helper.lng('noEntries')}</p>
        ` : ''}`
      }
    `}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default (props, { $f7, $on, $update }) => {
    let noCon = true;
    let cId = null;
    let cName = null; //'Zehm Dental Suisse',
    let registration, msg, list, isProfile, doc, isDirty, dynFields, cookie;
    let storage = window.localStorage;

    
    const renderProfile = function () {
        const posAllAgb = $f7.$('#tab-reg-allAgb ul');
        const posClientAgb = $f7.$('#tab-reg-clientAgb ul');
        const posUser = $f7.$('#tab-reg-user .lastStatic');
        const posAnam = $f7.$('#tab-reg-anam ul');

        const tpl = '<li><div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title item-floating-label" $label$></div><div class="item-input-wrap">$field$</div></div></div></li>';
        const tplAgb = '<li><div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-input-wrap">$field$</div></div></div></li>';
        const tplCheckbox = '<li><div class="item-content item-input item-input-outline"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title item-label"></div><div class="item-input-wrap">$label$ $field$</div></div></div></li>';
        const inp = '<input class="field" tabindex="';

        $f7.mod.user.getFields(cId ? cId : $f7.store.state.clientId)
            .then(rs => {
                //if not found?
                if (!rs.fields) {
                    $f7.dialorg.alert('notFound');
                    return false;
                }

                dynFields = rs.fields;

                let i = 20;

                dynFields.forEach(f => {
                    let tmp = '';

                    switch (f.type) {
                        case 'radio':
                            if (f.id === 'frequency') {
                                tmp += '<br/><span>';

                            } else {
                                tmp += '<span class="' + (f.pos == 'anam' ? 'answer' : '' ) + '">';
                            }

                            //add text field
                            tmp += '<span class="medAnswer">' + (f.answer ? '<input class="hide width-100" placeholder="' + f.answer + '" name="ans_' + f.id + '" id="ans_' + f.id + '"/>' : '') + '</span>';

                            f.values.forEach(v => {
                                let checked = doc[f.id] == v.key || (doc['fields'] && doc['fields'][f.id]) == v.key ? ' checked' : '';

                                tmp +=
                                    //wrap med radio-btns
                                    (f.id.startsWith('med') ? '<span class="medical ' + v.key + checked + '">' : '') +

                                    inp + i + '" type="radio" name="' + f.id + '" id="' + f.id + '-' + v.key + '" value="' + v.key + '"' +

                                    checked +

                                    (!f.optional ? ' required' : '') +

                                    '/><label for="' + f.id + '-' + v.key + '"' +

                                    //anam and yes (only once) show red
                                    //(v.key === 'yes' && f.pos === 'anam' ? ' class="mandatory"' : '') + //&& field == v.key

                                    '>' + v.value + '</label>' +

                                    //wrap med radio-btns
                                    (f.id.startsWith('med') ? '</span>' : (f.id === 'frequency' ? '<br/>' : ''));

                                i++;
                            });

                            tmp += '</span>';

                            tmp = tplCheckbox.replace(/\$label\$/, '<span class="label" id="lbl-' + f.id + '">' + f.title + '</span>')
                                .replace(/\$field\$/, tmp);

                            break;

                        case 'agb':
                            f.points.forEach(p => {
                                tmp += '<p>' + p + '</p>';
                            });


                            tmp = tplAgb.replace(/\$field\$/, tmp);

                            break;

                        default:
                            tmp = inp + i + '" type="text" name="' + f.id + '" id="' + f.id + '" value="';

                            if (doc[f.id]) {
                                tmp += doc[f.id];

                            } else if (doc['fields'] && doc['fields'][f.id]) {
                                tmp += doc['fields'][f.id];
                            }

                            tmp += '" ' + (!f.optional ? ' required' : '') + '/>';


                            tmp = tpl.replace(/\$label\$>/, ' id="lbl-' + f.id + '">' + f.title)
                                .replace(/\$field\$/, tmp);
                    }

                    switch (f.pos) {
                        case 'allAgb':
                            posAllAgb.append(tmp);
                            break;

                        case 'anam':
                            //for css horizontal line
                            posAnam.append(tmp.replace(/<li>/, '<li class="med">'));
                            break;

                        case 'clientAgb':
                            posClientAgb.append(tmp);
                            break;

                        default:
                            posUser.append(tmp);
                    }

                    $f7.input.checkEmptyState('input[name=' + f.id + ']');

                    i++;
                });

                //click radio
                $f7.$('#tab-reg-user .field').keyup((e) => {
                    if (e.key === "Enter") {
                        let tmp = $f7.$(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().parent().parent().next();

                        if(tmp.length > 0) {
                            let tmp2 = tmp.find('.field');
                            if(tmp2.length > 0) {
                                if(tmp2[0].type == 'select-one') {
                                    openDrop(tmp2[0]);

                                } else {
                                    tmp2[0].focus();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            next();
                        }
                    }
                });

                //click radio
                posAnam.find('.medical').click((e) => {
                    e.currentTarget.children[0].click();
                    let tmp = $f7.$(e.currentTarget);
                    tmp.parent().find('.checked').removeClass('checked');
                    tmp.addClass('checked');

                    //show input
                    if(tmp.hasClass('yes')) {
                        $f7.$(tmp.parent().children()[0]).find('input').show();

                    } else {
                        $f7.$(tmp.parent().children()[0]).find('input').hide();
                    }

                    //todo scroll
//                                let p = $f7.$('.page-content');
//                                p.scrollTo(0, p.height() + p.scrollTo() + 45, 100);
                });

                //add agb checkboxes
                let allAgb = '<input type="checkbox" class="confirmAgbs field" name="allAgb" id="allAgb" value="' + new Date().toISOString() + '"' + (doc.allAgb ? ' checked="ckecked"' : '') + '/>' +
                    '<label class="action" for="allAgb">' + $f7.mod.helper.lng('confirmAllAgb') + '</label>';

                posAllAgb.append(allAgb);

                let clAgb = '<input type="checkbox" class="confirmAgbs field" name="clAgb" id="clAgb" value="' + new Date().toISOString() + '"' + (doc.clAgb ? ' checked="ckecked"' : '') + '/>' +
                    '<label class="action" for="clAgb">' + $f7.mod.helper.lng('confirmClientAgb').replace('$client$', cName) + '</label>';

                posClientAgb.append(clAgb);

                //set input values
                for (let x in doc) {
                    let obj = $f7.$('input[name=' + x + '], select[name=' + x + ']');

                    if(obj && obj.length == 0) continue;

                    if(obj[0].type == 'radio') {
                        $f7.$('input[name="' + x + '"][value="' + doc[x] + '"]').prop('checked', true);

                        //show answer input if yes
                        if(doc[x + '_answer']) {
                            let tmp = $f7.$('input[name="ans_' + x + '"]');
                            tmp.val(doc[x + '_answer']);
                            tmp.show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        obj.val(doc[x]);
                    }

                    $f7.input.checkEmptyState('input[name=' + x + ']');
                    $f7.input.checkEmptyState('select[name=' + x + ']');

                    //block basic inputs if prefilled in anamnese
                    if (doc[x] && !isProfile && !$f7.mod.user.isServicedesk()) {
                        switch (x) {
                            case 'firstname':
                            case 'surname':
                            case 'birthday':
                            case 'gender':
                                obj.prop('disabled', true);
                                break;
                        }
                        //user profile
                    } else if (doc[x]) {
                        switch (x) {
                            case 'firstname':
                            case 'surname':
                            case 'birthday':
                            case 'gender':
                                obj.prop('disabled', true);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if prefilled from user scroll down
                if (doc['gender']) {
                    $f7.$('.page-content').scrollTo(0, $f7.mod.helper.getOffset('input[name="gender"]').top - 200, 200);
                }

                var now = new Date();
                var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
                var weekLater = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
                let cal = $f7.calendar.create({
                    inputEl: '#birthday',
                    openIn: 'customModal',
                    header: false,
                    footer: true,
                    value: doc.birthday ? [doc.birthday] : null,
                    events: [
                        {
                            from: today,
                            to: weekLater
                        },
                        //- more events this day
                        {
                            date: today,
                            color: '#ff0000'
                        }
                    ],
                    on: {
                        change: (e, v) => {
                            e.$inputEl.val(v);
                            e.close();
                            e.$inputEl.parent().parent().parent().find('input').focus();
                        },

                    }
                });

                //scroll on medical click
                posAnam.find('input[type="radio"]').change((e) => {
                    $f7.$('.page-content').scrollTo(0, $f7.mod.helper.getOffset(e.target).top - 200, 200);

                    $f7.$('.page-content').find('.item-inner-active').removeClass('item-inner-active');
                    $f7.$(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().next().find('.item-inner').addClass('item-inner-active');
                });

//                    $f7.$('.field').change(function () {
//                        isDirty = true;
//                        $f7.store.dispatch('markDirty', isDirty);
//                    });

                //if registered user registers with a new client
                if ($f7.store.state.user && $f7.view.current.router.currentRoute.params.action != 'edit' && !$f7.mod.user.isServicedesk()) {
                    next();
                }
            });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by renaming my files, just removed the ".html" and left ".f7" as file type. i dont know if they are just not parsed anymore but app is building now

Comment: but it seams as if it has cost me the sourcemaps for ft templates even though the rollup-plugin-framework7 should include them